# C: how to return main usage?

Tags: c, string, arguments

So I have a function inside the main that just concatenates two strings passed into argument.

They are passed like this:

```
./main hello world
```

and will generate:

```
helloworld
```

But I need to have this when no arguments are passed:

```
./main
 main: Usage: str1 str2
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Check `argc`. It gives you the number of arguments (including the program name).

Comment: What do you know about the `argc` and `argv` arguments to the `main` function? The `c` in `argc` stands for *count*. It's a count of the number of elements in the `argv` array.

Comment: I know argc is the number of arguments passed, and argv is an array of the arguments passed

Comment: Then you really know all you need to know. If no arguments were passed, what would the possible values of `argc` be (don't forget that it actually can be zero, and that also most of the time the "program name" is in `argv[0]` and is counted by `argc`)?

Comment: argc = 1 or argc = 0 when no arguments are passed ? I mean I only do ./main

Comment: Does your code have something like this? `if(0 == argc)`. If not, it should be added.

Comment: And there you have it. If `argc < 2` then no arguments were passed, and you could print your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
...
int main(int argc, char *atgv[]) {
  if (argc < 3) // argc = number of arguments including name of program
  {
    printf("Usage: main str1 str2\n");
    return 1;
  }
  ...
}
```